# Extremely simple ajax XmlHttpRequest code not woking

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I've just started learning ajax on W3Schools site. On [Try it editor on W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first) page when I try the following code I get proper response as one can expect from the code.You can also try the code just copy and paste on the given link page "Submit Code" ,click on "Change content" button in the response.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script>
                function loadXMLDoc()
                {
                    var xmlhttp;
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    }
                    else
                    {// code for IE6, IE5
                        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                    {
                        if (xmlhttp.readyState==0)
                        {
                            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML="0: request not initialized";
                        }if (xmlhttp.readyState==1)
                        {
                            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML="Server connection establish";
    
                        }if (xmlhttp.readyState==2)
                        {
                            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML="Request has been sent";
                        }if (xmlhttp.readyState==3)
                        {
                            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML="Server is processing the request";
                        }
                        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                        {
                            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                        }
                    }
                    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_example.asp",true);
                    xmlhttp.send();
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
    
            <div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
            <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>
    
        </body>
    </html>
```

But when I try the same code in my own html file and click on the "change content" button I get the contend changed in this order(Please ingnore type mistakes)

- server connection established
- Request has been sent.

After that nothing happens.I am connected to the Internet and also able to open the link in browser(Firefox).What should I do?

Comment: [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access another domain address using ajax from code written within you local html file. Cross domain ajax requests require you to use `jsonp` to access that data.

In the first instance, since you are already within the w3schools domain when making the ajax request, it will work.

Comment: thanx redDevil for your quick response.